Platform Term 4.f - App Settings missing publicly available privacy policy URL Facebook Developer
Actually continuously Facebook rejected our app due to this reason and I don't have any idea what points are missing and what I want to add to the privacy policy & I put a link to the privacy policy on the settings and login screen already then also they rejecting so if anyone has any suggestion and any supported tool to create a privacy policy without violation please help me.
This response comes from Meta,


I am attaching my privacy policy content here,





Thanks in advance.

What is the URL to the privacy policy?

https://www.termsfeed.com/live/9beb1ba5-4033-4c9d-8dcb-c4a6cb1660a8
Above issue has fixed now but they create issue on play store privacy policy @WizKid
